# Perform a repeated measures ANOVA using mixed model

Tags: r, anova, mixed-models

My design is as follow : subjects had to complete a response-time based task. Each trial of this task was defined by a combination of four factors :

- Factor 1 (F1) : 2 levels
- Factor 2 (F2) : 2 levels
- Factor 3 (F3) : 2 levels
- Factor 4 (F4) : 2 levels

Each unique combination was repeated 4 times, resulting in a total of 64 trials (2x2x2x2x4), and each subject went through all 64 trials.

As the four factors are within-subject factors, I was initially going with a repeated measure ANOVA with the four factors predicting the response-time (RT), using aov. I should add that I am interested in the interaction between the four factors. Looking through multiple guides, I came up with this code :

```
data.aov <- aov(RT ~ F1 * F2 * F3 * F4 + 
            Error(subject / (F1 * F2 * F3 * F4)),
          data = my_data)
```

However, while gathering information on how to perform a repeated measure ANOVA using R, I read that it is not advised when there is an unbalanced number of repeats across individuals - unfortunately, this is my case, as I had to get rid of outliers (particularly high/low response times). I should rather use mixed models, which account for this lack of balance.

I have been looking for examples on how to transpose a repeated measures ANOVA to a mixed model. So far, I managed to understand that my factors are fixed, but "subject" is random. However, all the examples I found did not include multiple factors as independent variables.

My question is : what is the correct syntax for a mixed model with multiple predicting factors, especially regarding the error term ? I am using the nlme package.

Comment: "as I had to get rid of outliers (particularly high/low response times)" That does not seem good practice.

Comment: But anyway, probably `library(lmerTest); anova(lmer(RT ~ F1 * F2 * F3 * F4 + 
            (F1 * F2 * F3 * F4 | subject),
          data = my_data))`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I tend to agree with you, however this is based on previous work, and for some reasons I have to stick with this part of the data management.